# The regex.matches method is matching and counting wrongly

Tags: swift, regex, swift4

In a TextView the user can insert text and images, like a notes. To save the whole TextView content in the database (Realm), I replaced the image itself for a pattern "[image]imageName[/image]", so when I load back this data to the TextView, I want to replace back this pattern for the images. I made this function:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: txtNote.text)

        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.string.utf16.count)
        let regex = NSRegularExpression("[image](.*?)[/image]")

        for match in regex.matches(in: attributedString.string, options: [], range: range) {
            if let rangeForImageName = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: attributedString.string){

                let imageName = String(attributedString.string[rangeForImageName])

                if let image = loadImage(named: imageName) {

                    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                    attachment.image = image
                    let oldWidth = attachment.image!.size.width;
                    let scaleFactor = (oldWidth / (txtNote.frame.size.width - 10))

                    attachment.image = UIImage(cgImage: attachment.image!.cgImage!, scale: scaleFactor, orientation: .up)

                    let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

                    txtNote.textStorage.insert(attString, at: txtNote.selectedRange.location)
                } else {
                    print("Image not found")
                }
            }
        }
```

I also have this extension to avoid a try catch in the function above:

```
extension NSRegularExpression {
    convenience init(_ pattern: String) {
        do {
            try self.init(pattern: pattern)
        } catch {
            preconditionFailure("Illegal regular expression: \(pattern).")
        }
    }
}
```

The example that I'm running, the content on attributedString:

```
Like Gorillaz :D
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼[image]4397ACA6-ADDC-4977-8D67-9FF44F10384A.jpeg[/image]

[image]9BE22CA8-9C6C-4FF9-B46F-D8AF33703061.jpeg[/image]
￼
Etc.{
}
```

It should be 2 matches, and the image names should be: "4397ACA6-ADDC-4977-8D67-9FF44F10384A.jpeg" and "9BE22CA8-9C6C-4FF9-B46F-D8AF33703061.jpeg".

But my function is returning 14 matches and the image names like: "k", "ll", "", "]4397ACA6-ADDC-4977-8D67-9FF44F10384A.jp", "[", etc.

Any idea abou what I'm doing wrong? I've been research for some error like this unsuccessfully all day long.

Comment: Your regex is malformed, try with `"\\[image\\](.*?)\\[/image\\]"`. Or `"\\Q[image]\\E(.*?)\\Q[/image]\\E"`

Comment: Indeed! Thank you so much... I didn't find this way :)

Comment: Sure! It's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[image]` and `[/image]` form *character classes* that match single chars, the former matching `i`, `m`, `a`, `g` or `e` and the latter also matching `/`.

If you want to treat a part of a regex as a literal substring, you may "quote" it with `\Q...\E` operators:

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression("\\Q[image]\\E(.*?)\\Q[/image]\\E")
```

If you are sure what you are doing, escape the brackets manually, `"\\[image\\](.*?)\\[/image\\]"`.

See [Regular Expression Metacharacters](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Regular-Expression-Metacharacters) table:

> `\Q`   Quotes all following characters until `\E`.
>   `\E`   Terminates a `\Q` ... `\E` quoted sequence.

"Quotes" means "adds backslashes before the special chars to make them match as literal chars" here.